# C reading a renamed file

Tags: c, file, stdio

In C what if I read a file using a FILE pointers and `fgets` or `fread`
(like `FILE *f`) and the file is renamed ?

Comment: Give it a go, see what happens :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably it depends on the operating system.  Under Unix-like operating systems (eg. Linux), you can read the file not just if it's renamed, but even if it's deleted: an open filehandle refers to the file's data, not to its directory entry.

Comment: other filesystems/operating systems will not allow to rename to file if it is locked (fopen'ed) by another process

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect the result to be operating system specific, and probably even file system specific. There are no guarantees by C.